# In Cosmos JOIN over array or non-array objects

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am fetching data from CosmosDB. The document has array elements and non-array elements.

> "Records": {
> "Number": "1"             }
> . . "Records": [   {       "Number" : "2",     }   {       "Number" : "3",     }   ]

I tried used JOIN to iterate the Records, but 1st record is not fetching.

> SELECT  r["Number"] from c JOIN r in c.Records

Expected Output is

> { "Number" : "1" } { "Number" : "2" } { "Number" :
> "3" }

Kindly help to assist.

Comment: You've created a schema that differs between documents (some have a single element, some have an array of elements). As such, your JOIN isn't going to work. I would suggest refactoring your schema to always have an array (even with array size = 1), and then retry your query. As for the query itself, you haven't shared anything specific, so I can only guess that's the issue...

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon. CosmosDB documents are loaded from XML docs via ADF. We are using Cosmos mainly for schema-free data store. In this case we need to force the XML schema to fix the array stuff.

Comment: Right - totally ok to treat Cosmos DB as schema-free, but... that doesn't mean your queries will work correctly when you have multiple schemas for the same data, as you do here. You'd either need to convert one format to the other, so they all match for this particular data, or use two queries.